# MVC URL formatting/design

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, asp.net-mvc

In refactoring a lot of MVC code, I have run into an issue with my URL design. For example, let's say we have a `Venue` object

```
public class Venue 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

and an `Event` object

```
public class Event
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Venue Venue { get; set; }
}
```

So my initial set up was to have an action set up in the `EventController` like

```
public ActionResult List (long? ID) // http://example.org/API/Events/List/12
```

where the `ID` specified the Venue, so it would return a list of events for that venue. If an `ID` is not specified, it returns a list of **all** events. This results in a confusing URL, because the `ID` parameter is ambiguous and misleading.

I then thought to change it to

```
public ActionResult List (long? VenueID) // http://example.org/API/Events/List?VenueID=12
```

which makes a lot more sense and is more clear.

An even cleaner URL would exist if the action was moved to the `VenueController` and set up like

```
public ActionResult Events (long? ID) // http://example.org/API/Venue/12/Events
```

as the `ID` would clearly specify the `Venue`'s `ID`. The issue with this URL is that you are primarily dealing with `Event` objects in the `VenueController`, which seems wrong.

I have been leaning towards the first option (`http://example.org/API/Events/List?VenueID=12`) because, even though the other option is cleaner, it seems like I should keep the `Event` pages (as I view this List page as more related to the `Event` object) in the `EventController`. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best answer is going to be: **Decide what *you* want it to look like, then modify the routing to match.**

You can customize how the routing engine processes URLs.  See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) for examples.  Our website uses MVC, but you wouldn't be able to tell it from the URLs.

In your specific case, I'd suggest making a route which looks for the pattern `"Venue/{id}/Events"` and routes it to the `Event` controller.

Comment: You might even customize the router to redirect `http://example.org/API/Venue/{id}/Events` to `http://example.org/API/Events/List?VenueID={id}` and offer both URIs.

Comment: I hadn't thought about dealing with it using routing. Thanks.

Comment: @theyshookhands - Yeah, changing the routing isn't an intuitive part of working with MVC, since all the tutorials and examples assume the standard Controller/Action/ID format.  But it's powerful.  Glad it helped!